# Regex in R: how to fill dataframe with multiple matches to left and right of target string

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

(This is a follow-up to [Regex in R: match collocates of node word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943119/regex-in-r-match-collocates-of-node-word).)

I want to extract word combinations (collocates) to the left and to the right of a target word (node) and store the three elements in a dataframe.

**Data**:

```
GO <- c("This little sentence went on and went on. It was going on for quite a while. Going on for ages. It's still going on. And will go on and on, and go on forever.")
```

**Aim**:

The target word is the verb GO in any of its possible realizations, be it 'go', 'going', goes', 'gone, or 'went' and I'm interested in extracting **3 words** to the left of GO and to the right of GO. The three words can cross sentence boundaries but the extracted strings should not include punctuation.

**What I've tried so far**:

To extract left-hand collocates I've used `str_extract_all` from `stringr`:

```
unlist(str_extract_all(GO, "((\\s)?\\w+\\b){1,3}(?=\\s((g|G)o(es|ing|ne)?|went))"))
[1] "This little sentence" " went on and"         " It was"              "s still"             
[5] " And will"            " and"
```

This captures most but not all matches and includes spaces.
The extraction of the node, by contrast, looks okay:

```
unlist(str_extract_all(GO, "(g|G)o(es|ing|ne)?|went"))
[1] "went"  "went"  "going" "Going" "going" "go"    "go"
```

To extract the right hand collocates:

```
unlist(str_extract_all(GO, "(?<=(g|G)o(es|ing|ne)?|went)(\\s\\w+\\b){1,3}"))
[1] " on and went"  " on"           " on for quite" " on for ages"  " on"           " on and on"   
[7] " on forever"
```

Again the matches are incomplete and unwanted spaces are included.
And finally assembling all the matches in a dataframe throws an error:

```
collocates <- data.frame(
  Left = unlist(str_extract_all(GO, "((\\s)?\\w+\\b){1,3}(?=\\s((g|G)o(es|ing|ne)?|went))")),
  Node = unlist(str_extract_all(GO, "(g|G)o(es|ing|ne)?|went")),
  Right = unlist(str_extract_all(GO, "(?<=(g|G)o(es|ing|ne)?|went)(\\s\\w+\\b){1,3}"))); collocates
Error in data.frame(Left = unlist(str_extract_all(GO, "((\\s)?\\w+\\b){1,3}(?=\\s((g|G)o(es|ing|ne)?|went))")),  : 
      arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 7
```

**Expected output**:

```
Left                    Node    Right
This little sentence    went    on and went
went on and             went    on It was
on It was              going    on for quite
quite a while          Going    on for ages
ages It’s still        going    on And will
on And will               go    on and on
and on and                go    on forever
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using quanteda package? You can handle this type of operation with `kwic()`.

Comment: The results are not quite clear. You seem to want partly overlapping matches. Check `str_match_all(GO, "(?i)(?:(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){0,2})\\s+)?\\b(go(?:es|ing|ne)?|went)\\b(?:\\s+(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){0,2}))?")`, is it good enough?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's good but not perfect: it produces just six rows but there should be seven and it doesn't match all the collocates.

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks, that's pretty awesome if `valuetype = "regex"`is added.

Comment: As I said, it is not quite clear how you want to get `went on and    | went   | on It was` since the previous one "eats up" `went`, and no other overlapping matches are expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Does the fact that your solution does not solve the problem really warrant a downvote on my question?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I just posted an example with `kwic()`. I wonder if this is sufficient enough for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Quanteda, you can get the following result. When you deal with texts, you want to use small letters. I converted capital letters with `tolower()`. I also removed `.` and `,` with `gsub()`. Then, I applied `kwic()` to the text. If you do not mind losing capital letters, dots, and commas, you get pretty much what you want.

```
library(quanteda)
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)

myvec <- c("go", "going", "goes", "gone", "went")

mytext <- gsub(x = tolower(GO), pattern = "\\.|,", replacement = "")

mydf <- kwic(x = mytext, pattern = myvec, window = 3) %>% 
        as_tibble %>%
        select(pre, keyword, post) %>% 
        cSplit(splitCols = c("pre", "post"), sep = " ", direction = "wide", type.convert = FALSE) %>% 
        select(contains("pre"), keyword, contains("post"))

   pre_1  pre_2    pre_3 keyword post_1  post_2 post_3
1:  this little sentence    went     on     and   went
2:  went     on      and    went     on      it    was
3:    on     it      was   going     on     for  quite
4: quite      a    while   going     on     for   ages
5:  ages   it's    still   going     on     and   will
6:    on    and     will      go     on     and     on
7:   and     on      and      go     on forever   <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks, the quanteda package is really an eye opener!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Yes, I think it is a great tool if you wanna handle text data.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort and your assistance. I've accepted your answer in recognition of that effort and help and to make sure that at least one of us gets the small increase in reputation that comes with getting an answer accepted (accepting your own answer gets you nothing).

Answer (score 1):

A little late but not too late for posterity or contemporaries doing collocation research on unannotated text, here's my own answer to my question. Full credit is given to @jazzurro's pointer to `quanteda`and his answer.

My question was: how to compute collocates of a given node in a text **and** store the results in a dataframe (that's the part not addressed by @jazzurro).

**Data**:

```
GO <- c("This little sentence went on and went on. It was going on for quite a while. 
    Going on for ages. It's still going on. And will go on and on, and go on forever.")
```

**Step 1**: Prepare data for analysis

```
go <- gsub("[.!?;,:]", "", tolower(GO))   # get rid of punctuation
go <- gsub("'", " ", tolower(go))         # separate clitics from host
```

**Step 2**: Extract KWIC using regex pattern and argument `valuetype = "regex"`

```
concord <- kwic(go, "go(es|ing|ne)?|went", window = 3, valuetype = "regex")
concord                                                       
  [text1, 4] this little sentence | went  | on and went 
  [text1, 7]          went on and | went  | on it was   
 [text1, 11]            on it was | going | on for quite
 [text1, 17]        quite a while | going | on for ages 
 [text1, 24]           it s still | going | on and will 
 [text1, 28]          on and will |  go   | on and on   
 [text1, 33]           and on and |  go   | on forever
```

**Step 3**: Identify strings with fewer collocates than defined by window:

```
# Number of collocates on the left:
concord$nc_l <- unlist(lengths(strsplit(concordance$pre, " "))); concord$nc_l
[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3   # nothing missing here
# Number of collocates on the right:
concord$nc_r <- unlist(lengths(strsplit(concordance$post, " "))); concord$nc_r
[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 2   # last string has only two collocates
```

**Step 4**: Add NA to strings with missing collocates:

```
# define window:
window <- 3
# change string:
concord$post[!concord$nc_r == window] <- paste(concord$post[!concord$nc_r == window], NA, sep = " ")
```

**Step 5**: Fill dataframe with slots for collocates and node, using `str_extract` from library `stringr`as well as regex with lookarounds to determine split points for collocates:

```
library(stringr)
L3toR3 <- data.frame(
  L3 = str_extract(concord$pre, "^\\w+\\b"),
  L2 = str_extract(concord$pre, "(?<=\\s)\\w+\\b(?=\\s)"),
  L1 = str_extract(concord$pre, "\\w+\\b$"),
  Node = concord$keyword,
  R1 = str_extract(concord$post, "^\\w+\\b"),
  R2 = str_extract(concord$post, "(?<=\\s)\\w+\\b(?=\\s)"),
  R3 = str_extract(concord$post, "\\w+\\b$")
)
```

**Result**:

```
L3toR3
     L3     L2       L1  Node R1      R2    R3
1  this little sentence  went on     and  went
2  went     on      and  went on      it   was
3    on     it      was going on     for quite
4 quite      a    while going on     for  ages
5    it      s    still going on     and  will
6    on    and     will    go on     and    on
7   and     on      and    go on forever    NA
```

Comment: @jazzurro This is really the solution I was looking for. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I am glad that you found your way. I updated my answer to show you another way to achieve your goal. Have a look. You can type less.